# Is there a way to convert QDomNode text to QString?

Tags: qt

I have a QDomDocument called doc and I need to make a QStringList of each of its top-level children. So far I have this:

```
QDomNodeList nodes = doc.childNodes();
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
{
    QDomText text = nodes.at(i).toText();
    //do something here...
}
```

However, I cannot find any way to convert this to a QString. This is my first time ever working with The QDom* classes, so I'm pretty confused, and going by the docs there doesn't seem like much can be done with QDomText. Can anyone please offer some advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent QDomElement has a method [QDomElement::text()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtxml/qdomelement.html#text) returning the contents of the text node. Operating on the QDomElement level and using text() should be the most simple and standard way to get the element text.

Alternatively, you can call [QDomCharacterData::data()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtxml/qdomcharacterdata.html#data) (QDomCharacterData is a baseclass of QDomText) in cases where you go down to the QDomText node level.

Comment: EDIT: You can actually disregard this follow-up question, I'm just going to leave it there if anyone else has similar questions sometime. I found I can use <code>QString s = nodes.at(i).toElement()</code> to make it the proper class for the function. Thanks a lot again for your help! :)

ORIGINAL COMMENT: Thanks a lot, I didn't know those functions existed. I'm not quite sure how I would call them though. I tried something like <code>QString s = nodes.at(i).QDomElement::text()</code> but that threw an error. Am I simply getting the sytax of it wrong?